# not able to read a file above 1600 lines using stream java?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, filereader

I am reading a large file having 5000 lines using stream.

- I have to skip lines because want show recent lines.
- eg. if user pass 100 in argument then he will see last 100 lines.

My code:

```
public static void readFile(String filePath, long lineNum) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    long totalLines, startLine = 0;

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        totalLines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).count();
        startLine = totalLines - lineNum;
        // Stream<String> line32 = lines.skip(((startLine)+1));

        list = lines.skip(startLine + 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // lines.forEach(list::add);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: I have check it by other file also but steel the same problem.** If i am not using skip ,and just read the stream then also it doesn't print whole content of file **

Comment: I've tried you code with /usr/share/dict/words (which is 99171 lines long on my system and it works just nice for me (returns last 100 lines). Which JRE/JDK do you use ?

Comment: If `totalLines` contains the correct number, iterating over all lines worked at least once. Not that you don't close you second stream, but it shouldn't have such impact.

Comment: @zeppelin i used 1.2_121 jdk...if i read whole file then it gives random output every time...start readfrom any position

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Works for me as well. Tested with a text file with 6441 lines.

Comment: `1.2_121 jdk` hmm, looks weird to me, what does `java -version` say ?

Comment: @GKR No i didn't get any exception

Comment: can some one share the text file...may be i am using wrong formatting..!?

Comment: @NeelaySolanki - I've used a regular `/usr/share/dict/words` (should be available on almost any Linux system). Maybe you can share one of your files too ?

Comment: @zeppelin readFile("/usr/share/dict/american-english", 99100); still get output start from 'thriftier' word

Comment: @NeelaySolanki please try to reduce your test case to `Files.lines(Paths.get("/usr/share/dict/words")).skip(100).collect(Collectors.toList())`, and see if it produces a correct result.

Comment: @zeppelin yes it gives correct output..how to send the list to jsp file with separated line.i mean each word on new line

Comment: Thanks for your support.:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).